# Передача данных с PYTHON на HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

Как можно передать данные с PYTHON на HTML. При отображении страницы что бы уже были например:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="**с python**">
```

Comment: Через шаблоны, например см. тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/193260/

Comment: Спасибо вроде получился, еще до конца пока не дошел.

Answer (score 1):

У Flask есть метод [`render_template`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=render_template#template-rendering), и в него можно передать свои параметры.

**Пример кода**:

1. python

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    data = 'Эта строка была получена из Python!'
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

2. html

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="{{ data }}">
```